# Community password expiration

Tags: community, reset-password

For my community login, I have a custom vf page to which the user is redirected if his password has expired for him to reset his password. Also, when the user's password is reset manually from the back-end the link in the password reset mail redirects the user to the same vf page. I need an identifier in the custom vf page for whether the redirection is from the mail link or due to password expiry. Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The email sent is standard salesforce functionality. I doubt we can add the parameter there. @identigral

Comment: You're going to need to take over production of email content (body/subject) for at least one of these two scenarios. With password reset, this is pretty easy to do with email templates and [`System.resetPasswordWithEmailTemplate(..)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_system_resetPasswordWithEmailTemplate)